# Ember.js error "Cannot read property 'container' of undefined" when using Liquid Fire

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm a beginner to front-end development and trying to utilize Ember.js for my project. I stumbled upon [a great talk by Edward Faulkner about Liquid Fire](https://youtu.be/p8aF-7-_cE8) at EmberConf 2015. It looked incredibly easy to apply and so I decided to give it a try.

My app is using Ember and Ember-Data Canary via ember-cli 0.2.0.

The structure of the app is somewhat like this:

```
application.hbs
  \users
     \user
        work.hbs
        profile.hbs
        ...
     user.hbs
```

And the part of the *router.js* file that's responsible for this is:

```
this.resource('users', function (){
    this.resource('users.user', { path: '/:user_id' }, function () {
        this.route('work');
        this.route('profile');
        ...
    });
});
```

After I installed the addon with `npm install --save-dev liquid-fire`, I replaced {{outlet}} in my *user.hbs* file with {{liquid-outlet}} and added a *transitions.js* file with some simple transition data:

```
export default function () {
  this.transition(
    this.toRoute('users.user'),
    this.use('fade')
  );
}
```

But as soon as I navigate to the user page, I get a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined
```

Which originates in a *liquid-outlet.js* file, on line 15:

```
var View = this.container.lookupFactory("view:liquid-outlet");
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. It seems like there's something with my {{liquid-outlet}} being placed in the wrong place or something, but I've tried moving it elsewhere, with no luck. As soon as I navigate to a template that has {{liquid-outlet}} in it, I get the same error. Please help.

Thank you,
Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in liquid fire's master branch. You can get a working build for now by pulling from git with:

```
npm install ef4/liquid-fire --save-dev
```

The next release will of course also include the fix.

Check this github issue thread for updates: https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/issues/190